# Cross compile using GNU as to Windows executable from Linux box

Tags: assembly, gnu, cross-compiling

Is there anyway to tell GNU as to generate Windows PE executable file from Linux?
I know you can use Cygwin or MingW,but sometime I don't have access to windows machine.

Comment: figured out.. GNU as only generate obj file, it is the linker that must be configure to generate Windows PE

Comment: Code generation is different too, because calling conventions (the "ABI") are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a toolchain targetting Windows and hosted on Linux.

Such things do exist, look at http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/download%20filename%20structure for intance. You will need something like `mingw-w64-bin_x86_64-linux*`` for a mingw targeting Win64 and hosted on Linux x86_64.